# '=' expected near 'local' roblox lua

Tags: lua, roblox

I get an error that says in line 3, '=' expected near 'local'.
I'm trying this : `local = fireball = game.ServerStorage.Fireball.`
I typed the equal sign where I thought it needs to go, but it doesn't  work...
This is the code :

```
local cannon = script.Parent
local barrel = script Workspace.cannontrap.TrapBarrel
local = fireball = game.ServerStorage.Fireball

while true do
    local fireballCopy = fireball:Clone()
    fireballCopy.Parent = game.Workspace
    fireballCopy.Position = barrel.Position
    fireballCopy.Velocity = Vector3.new(-80,0,0)
    wait(8)
end
```

(Line 3 is incorrect for this error).

Comment: Where is says "This is the code, it also includes the bottom code, so it's also code.

Comment: `script Workspace` probably should contain a dot in between.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is clear. This line

```
local = fireball = game.ServerStorage.Fireball
```

should be

```
local fireball = game.ServerStorage.Fireball
```

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be a "=" after the local it should be

```
local fireball = game.ServerStorage.Fireball
```

Hope this helps!